# PHP Is post_max_size the size of all inputs added up together?

Tags: php

Hi i recently found out that my web hoster only allows a max of 128mb  for post_max_size. I was wondering if I post two things in the same form. Lets pretend one of them is 100mb and the other is 60mb. Does this exceed the limit? Is the limit per input or per inputs all added up in the same form?

Comment: I'm afraid that's correct. It's the size of ALL post data on the page.